# How to catch keydown in iframe after opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, fancybox

Fancybox shows pikachoose image viewer in iframe.
Keyboard keys are used to  navigate between images
On initial load keys are ignored.
Keys will work only if clicked in fancybox.
I added

```
              $('.pikachoose').focus();
```

but this does not enable keys.
How to allow keys to work immediately if iframe is opened ?

iframe content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" <html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="Pikachoose/bottom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Pikachoose/jquery.pikachoose.full.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#pikame").PikaChoose({
                    autoPlay: false
                });

                $("html").keydown(function (evt) {
                    $('#pikame').data('pikachoose').Next();
                });
              // why this does not allow keydown event:
              $('.pikachoose').focus();
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pikachoose">
        <ul id="pikame">
            <li>
                <img src="img1" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img2" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img3" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is for an id, not a class.

Either change your javascript to `$(".pikachoose").focus()` or change `class="pikachoose"` to `id="pikachoose"`.

edit:

You can't normally focus arbitrary elements, like divs. But there is a pseudo-hack that may work: puting a tabindex on the element. You can use -1 to prevent unwanted interference with tabbing. So either put `tabindex="-1"` on that div or you can put `$(".pikachoose").attr("tabindex", -1).focus()` in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I changed code to `                  $('.pikachoose').focus();` but problem persists. I updated question.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't focusing (ha!) on the fact you were trying to focus() a div. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. It this best practice or should I set focus to some other element?

Comment: For your scenario (handling keystrokes) it seems like a good solution. If you're dealing with form elements you can be more specific and focus something that can really have focus: `$(":input").first().focus()`

Comment: If clicked inside iframe, in its background, it receives focus without using tabindex=-1 . Which element receives focus ? Maybe keydown can set focus to the same element?

Comment: I had the same challenge just with galleria and found this to work quite nice:  
`$(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#main").attr("tabindex",-1).focus().blur();`